# Weird HTML Load behavior on localhost - Xampp

Tags: xampp

Below is the strange behaviour which we observed today in our development lab, unable to understand how to fix it, thought of taking community help.

[Behavior: Problem Loading when accessing page using Http://localhost/blaxer/mdlhdrworking.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smpff.gif)

[Behavior: There is no problem loading when accessing the file directly from the folder (double-click the file )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAG0y.gif)

Comment: Can you post screenshot of error that displayed on link click...

Comment: which xampp version you are using?

Comment: Thank you Moiz, there is no error message per say. when i open the files, there is lag. 

xampp version is 7.2.7